# get iron-ajax response as a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer, response

Apologies for the lame title, but I couldn't find anything better.

So here's my problem: I get datas using iron-ajax, I bind the "on-response" in my dom-repeat and get a table. Fine.

But I would also like to access to the ajax-response in my javascript part, as a variable, so I can use methods such as .length to use in a "for" loop for instance.

here's what I've tried so far, by reading others posts on this forum, but doesn't work:

```
<iron-ajax id="videosAjax" auto
url="http://mysuperawesome/service"
params='{}'
handle-as="json"
last-response="{{ajaxResponse}}"></iron-ajax>

        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{videosList}}">      
                <div class="colM">[[item.id]]</div>           
        </template>
```

and the script part:

```
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'videos',
        ajaxResponse: function (data) {
          this.videosList = data.detail.response;
          console.log(this.videosList);
        },
...

this.async(function () {
   var count = this.videosList.length;
   document.getElementById("videosCount").innerText = count;
</script>
```

But no, the console.log still returns "undefined" :(

Answer (score 2):

Your example has [`last-response="{{ajaxResponse}}"`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax#property-lastResponse), which binds the response to a property named `ajaxResponse`, which would allow other elements in the template to bind to it ([jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vufegi/edit?html,output)).

Since you want to notify a callback, you would instead use `on-response="METHOD"`, where, `METHOD` is the name of a method on your Polymer object. Actually, the method would look very similar to what your example currently has as `ajaxResponse()`.

Here's a working demo (based on [`iron-ajax/demo/index.html`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-ajax/blob/4a9f0c9/demo/index.html)):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <iron-ajax auto url="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search"
          params='{"part":"snippet", "q":"polymer", "key": "AIzaSyAuecFZ9xJXbGDkQYWBmYrtzOGJD-iDIgI", "type": "video"}'
          handle-as="json"
          on-response="handleResponse"
          debounce-duration="300"></iron-ajax>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'x-foo',
        handleResponse: function(e) {
          console.log(e.detail.response);
        }
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
</html>
```

<sup>[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/cucofi/edit?html,console)</sup>

Comment: Not sure why this answer wasn't accepted, worked nicely for me.

Answer (score 0):

As [documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax) say´s

> lastResponse Object
>
> lastRequest's response.
>
> Note that lastResponse and lastError are set when lastRequest
> finishes, so if loading is true, then lastResponse and lastError will
> correspond to the result of the previous request.
>
> The type of the response is determined by the value of handleAs at the
> time that the request was generated.

So, in your code I think that `ajaxResponse` should be an object, not a function.

```
properties:{
    ajaxResponse:{
        type:Object,
        value: function(){return {};}
    }
},
```

That object will contains your ajax response.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't get how I can acces to the ".length" property of the response?